# Exporting a List is producing an empty CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have a two lists that are zipped together, i am able to print the list out to view but i when i try to export the list into a csv file, the csv file is created but its empty. not sure why as im using the same method to save the two lists separately and it works.

```
import csv
import random
import datetime
import calendar

with open("Duty Name List.csv") as CsvNameList:
NameList = CsvNameList.read().split("\n")
date = datetime.datetime.now()
MaxNumofDays = calendar.monthrange(date.year,date.month)

print (NameList)
print(date.year)
print(date.month)
print(MaxNumofDays[1])

x = MaxNumofDays[1] + 1
daylist = list(range(1,x))
print(daylist)

ShuffledList = random.sample(NameList,len(daylist))
print(ShuffledList)


RemainderList = set(NameList) - set(ShuffledList)
print(RemainderList)

with open("remainder.csv","w") as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f,delimiter="\n")
    wr.writerow(RemainderList)

AssignedDutyList = zip(daylist,ShuffledList)
print(list(AssignedDutyList))

with open("AssignedDutyList.csv","w") as g:
    wr = csv.writer(g)
    wr.writerow(list(AssignedDutyList))
```

no error messages are produced.

Comment: Its working fine for me, what are the contents of your two list? pls provide full example so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: daylist is just a list of numbers from 1 - 31, the other list is just 30 names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3, This line

```
AssignedDutyList = zip(daylist,ShuffledList)
```

creates an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/classes.html#iterators) named `AssignedDutyList`.

This line

```
print(list(AssignedDutyList))
```

*exhausts* the iterator.  When this line is executed

```
wr.writerow(list(AssignedDutyList))
```

the iterator has no further output, so nothing is written to the file.

The solution is to store the result of calling `list` on the iterator in a variable rather than the iterator itself, in cases where the content of an iterator must be reused.

```
AssignedDutyList = list(zip(daylist,ShuffledList))
print(AssignedDutyList)

with open("AssignedDutyList.csv","w") as g:
    wr = csv.writer(g)
    wr.writerow(AssignedDutyList)
```

As a bonus, the name `AssignedDutyList` now refers to an actual list, and so is less confusing for future readers of the code.